# weird GC behaviour with CMUCL

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Why is this code overflowing the heap with CMUCL? Even if i give it 400MB memory `(setq extensions:*bytes-consed-between-gcs* 400000000)` CMUCL  will still choke on it.

```
; [GC threshold exceeded with 12,012,544 bytes in use.  Commencing GC.]
; [GC completed with 188,064 bytes retained and 11,824,480 bytes freed.]
; [GC will next occur when at least 400,188,064 bytes are in use.]
; [GC threshold exceeded with 400,202,280 bytes in use.  Commencing GC.]
; [GC completed with 207,120 bytes retained and 399,995,160 bytes freed.]
; [GC will next occur when at least 400,207,120 bytes are in use.]
```

This code runs ok with CCL and SBCL, though i havent looked at their memory usage.

Is this a bug in CMUCL?? I believe all these func's are tail recursive.

```
(defun sqrt-iter (guess x)
  (if (good-enough? guess x)
      guess
      (sqrt-iter (improve guess x)
                 x)))

(defun improve (guess x)
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(defun average (x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(defun good-enough? (guess x)
  (< (abs (- (* guess guess) x)) 0.001))

(defun mysqrt (x)
  (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))

(defun zint (x acc step)
  (setq num-iter (+ 1 num-iter))
  (if (>= x 10000.0)
      acc
      (zint (+ x step)
           (+ acc (* step (mysqrt x)))
           step)))

(setq num-iter 0)
(format t "result=~A; iterations=~A~%" (zint 0.0 0.0 .001) num-iter)
(quit)
```

**EDIT:**
Yes, CMUCL definitely conses a lot and unnecessarily. Try this simple example:

```
$ ~/cmucl/bin/lisp 
...
* (defun foo () (bar))

FOO
* (defun bar () (foo))

BAR
* (foo)
; [GC threshold exceeded with 12,009,008 bytes in use.  Commencing GC.]
; [GC completed with 111,816 bytes retained and 11,897,192 bytes freed.]
; [GC will next occur when at least 12,111,816 bytes are in use.]
; [GC threshold exceeded with 12,120,912 bytes in use.  Commencing GC.]
; [GC completed with 120,016 bytes retained and 12,000,896 bytes freed.]
; [GC will next occur when at least 12,120,016 bytes are in use.]
; [GC threshold exceeded with 12,133,576 bytes in use.  Commencing GC.]
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two functions which are 'tail recursive': sqr-iter and zint.

**General advice**:

To let the compiler optimize these, the DEBUG optimization level needs to be 2 or less.

You can see if the compiler generates tail recursive code by disassembling them. Use the function `disassemble`.

The GC invocation itself is not a problem. Most implementations don't print anything on GC. CMUCL prints it by default (IIRC). CMUCL may allocate huge amounts of floats for un-optimized code - which then might cause a lot of GCs.

Only if CMUCL has a stack overflow you would see that the tail call optimization is not working. GCs themselves only show large amounts of consing.

So to debug your problem you need first to see if the code is compiled with tail call optimization on. You can disassemble the code. Another option is to put the code while running into the debugger and then by looking at the stack backtrace. On the stack there should not be a large number of recursive calls - they would be replaced by jumps.

If the code is running with constant stack space, then you need to look at the allocation of floats. You would need to check then that the code does not allocate too much floats.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the settings
... This is SBCL which is related.

```
* (declaim (optimize (speed 0) (compilation-speed 0) (safety 3) (debug 3)))
* (defun foo () (bar))
* (defun bar () (foo))
*  (foo)
INFO: Control stack guard page unprotected
Control stack guard page temporarily disabled: proceed with caution

INFO: Control stack guard page reprotected
#<sb-kernel::control-stack-exhausted {1002DBD4D3}>
```

but if you tell it you want it to go fast and not worry about debugging... it does better

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (compilation-speed 0) (safety 1) (debug 0)))
(defun foo () (bar))
(defun bar () (foo))
(foo)  ;;; CPU topped out, but no stack issues or garbage collecting
```